# Is there a way to load/update the data without removing feature layer and without flicker effect using arcgis javascript api 4

Tags: angular, arcgis-js-api

I am creating a feature layer from feature collection by fetching data from external query service and adding to the map with some data.

As per my project need I have to refresh the data on the map after every 5 seconds. To achieve this I am requesting data using external query and after getting the response data I am removing the previous feature layer and adding a new one.

**Issues**:
While adding the new layer on the map it takes a little time (~1 sec) to reflect the feature on the map which looks like a flicker effect.

**Question**:
Is there a way to load/update the data without removing feature layer and without flicker effect (only added/removed features should reflect on the map )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are removing the layer with the old features and adding a new one with the new features. You don't need to do that.

Use `FeatureLayer` function `applyEdits`, to remove all the features and add the new ones in "one" operation.

[ArcGIS JS Docs - FeatureLayer applyEdits](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#applyEdits)

UPDATE:

Take a look at the example I made for you.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>ArcGIS API for JavaScript Hello World App</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/esri/css/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/"></script>

  <script>
    require([
      'esri/Map',
      'esri/views/MapView',
      'esri/layers/FeatureLayer',
      'esri/Graphic'
    ], function (Map, MapView, FeatureLayer, Graphic) {

      const quakesUrl =
        'https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/ks_earthquakes_since_2000/FeatureServer/0';
      
      const quakesLayer = new FeatureLayer({
        url: quakesUrl,
        visible: false
      });

      let lastAddFeatureResults = [];

      const resultsLayer = new FeatureLayer({
        source: [],
        geometryType: 'point',
        renderer: {
          type: 'simple',
          symbol: {
            type: 'simple-marker',
            style: 'circle',
            size: `8px`,
            color: [255, 0, 0, .6],
            outline: {
              color: 'black',
              width: '0.5px'
            }
          }
        },
        fields: [
          {
            name: 'OBJECTID',
            alias: 'ObjectID',
            type: 'oid'
          },
          {
            name: 'time',
            alias: 'Time',
            type: 'string'
          },
          {
            name: 'mag',
            alias: 'Magnitude',
            type: 'double'
          },
          {
            name: 'magType',
            alias: 'Magnitude Type',
            type: 'string'
          },
          {
            name: 'place',
            alias: 'Place',
            type: 'string'
          },
          {
            name: 'type',
            alias: 'Type',
            type: 'string'
          }
        ],
        popupEnable: true,
        popupTemplate: {
          title: '{place}'
        }
      });

      const map = new Map({
        basemap: "gray",
        layers: [quakesLayer, resultsLayer]
      });

      const view = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: map,
        center: [-97.75188, 37.23308],
        zoom: 9
      });

      function queryEarthquakes() {
        const query = quakesLayer.createQuery();
        query.where = "mag >= 3";
        
        return quakesLayer.queryFeatures(query);
      }

      function displayResults(results) {
        const addFeatures = results.features;
        resultsLayer.applyEdits({
          addFeatures,
          deleteFeatures: lastAddFeatureResults
        }).then(results => {
          console.log(results.addFeatureResults);
          console.log(results.deleteFeatureResults);
          lastAddFeatureResults = results.addFeatureResults;
        });
      }

      function updateLayer() {
        console.timeLog('update layer');
        queryEarthquakes().then(displayResults);
      }
      
      console.time('update layer');

      updateLayer();

      setInterval(updateLayer, 5000);

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i am removing layer because when fetching data we don't know which data updated/added/deleted so removing all and re-added. Apply edits not working because the layer is created by feature collection so no URL.

Comment: the correct way of add/update/delete features in a `FeatureLayer` is using `applyEdits`, with remote or local data. Take a look at the example I made for you.

Comment: One more thing Currently, after applying edits in response all features object id is the same.

Comment: Maybe didn't understand correctly the problem .. One question, why not just refreshing the layer every 5 minutes?, I am thinking in `definitionExpression` and `refresh` method

Comment: In every 5 seconds we fetching data from external data i.e. live data but from external service, we can't find which is updated/added/deleted data so we just remove layer and re-added. From external query service when we fetch data we have one field which value is unique so we are using that field as a objectid value while creating feature layer

Comment: I guess a good strategy then would be to keep record of current ids, and use that in order to know what to do. It is a fixed number of features or can vary?, how many features are we talking about? (aprox) as a whole and in requests.

Comment: random features. Now I am using apply edits by adding a custom field at the client side while creating layer.